# use Airflow connection from a jinja template

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to pass DB params to BashOperator using environment variables, but I can't find any documentation/examples how to use a connection from a Jinja template.

So I'm looking for something similar to variables

```
echo {{ var.value.<variable_name> }}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**For Airflow >= 2.2.0**:

Assuming you have conn id `test_conn` you can use macros directly via:

`{{ conn.test_conn }}` so you get any connection attribute like:

`{{ conn.test_conn.host }}`, `{{ conn.test_conn.login }}`, `{{ conn.test_conn.password }}` and so on.

**For Airflow < 2.2.0**:

There is no ready to use macro however you can create custom macros to address this.

Connection example:

[image]

Creating the macros:

```
def get_host(conn_id):
    connection = BaseHook.get_connection(conn_id)
    return connection.host

def get_schema(conn_id):
    connection = BaseHook.get_connection(conn_id)
    return connection.schema

def get_login(conn_id):
    connection = BaseHook.get_connection(conn_id)
    return connection.login
```

Using them in a DAG:

```
def print_function(**context):
    print(f"host={context['host']} schema={context['schema']} login={context['login']}")

user_macros = {
    'get_host': get_host,
    'get_schema': get_schema,
    'get_login': get_login,
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='connection',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    user_defined_macros=user_macros,
) as dag:

# Example how to use as function
python_op = PythonOperator( 
    task_id='python_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_function,
    op_kwargs={
        'host': get_host("test_conn"),
        'schema': get_schema("test_conn"),
        'login': get_login("test_conn"),
    }
)

# Example how to use as Jinja string
bash_op = BashOperator( 
    task_id='bash_task',
    bash_command='echo {{ get_host("test_conn") }} {{ get_schema("test_conn") }} {{ get_login("test_conn") }} ',
)
```

Rendering for `PythonOperator` example:
[image]

[image]

Rendering for `BashOperator` example:

[image]

General Explnation:
What this code does is creating a custom function `func()` to be used as `user_defined_macros` thus providing the ability to use it just like this macro was defined by Airflow itself.
You can access the templating as: `{{ func() }}` as seen in the example the function allow accept parameters.

**Note** you can create such functions for all fields in the connection object.

be cautious with how you use it, passing passwords as text may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 7):

My [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/16686) added the `{{ conn.my_conn_id.login }}` syntax and it will be available in airflow 2.2.0 (**not released yet** as of 2021-09-22).

See the unreleased documentation for [templates reference](http://apache-airflow-docs.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/docs/apache-airflow/latest/templates-ref.html) here

For 2.1.4 and earlier:

Improving on previous answers,

#### Define macro per DAG: `{{conn.<conn_id>}}`

you can get  `conn.<connection_name>.host` syntax by using the following macro:

```
class ConnectionGrabber:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return  Connection.get_connection_from_secrets(name)
dag = DAG(user_defined_macros={'connection': ConnectionGrabber()}
```

that injects the name `connection` into the jinja template context, `connection` is a `ConnectionGrabber` instance. This `ConnectionGrabber` provides dynamic/managed attributes, so when you request attribute `my_conn_id` (like  `connection.my_conn_id`) it will perform a lookup of using the `airflow.models.Connection.get_connection_from_secrets` and return that, from there you can use the `a.m.Connection` attributes like `host`, `login`, `password`, etc.

Complete example where the connection `mssql` is accessed in jinja template with `bash_command='echo {{connection.mssql.host }}'`:

```
from airflow.models import DAG,Connection
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


class ConnectionGrabber:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return  Connection.get_connection_from_secrets(name)


args = {'owner': 'airflow', 'retries': 3, 'start_date': days_ago(2)}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_connection',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
    user_defined_macros={'connection': ConnectionGrabber()}
)

task = BashOperator(task_id='read_connection', bash_command='echo {{connection.mssql.host }}', dag=dag)
```

#### Define macro in a plugin: `{{macros.conn.value.<conn_id>}}`

If you wanted to use this macro in all your DAGs you can wrap it in a plugin like so:

```
# $AIRFLOW_HOME/plugins/connection_macro.py
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from airflow.models import Connection


class ConnectionGrabber:
    __name__ = "value"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__name__
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return  Connection.get_connection_from_secrets(name)

class MacrosPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "conn"
    macros = [ConnectionGrabber()]
```

check that the plugin can be loaded with `airflow plugins`

```
airflow plugins
name | source                    | macros
=====+===========================+=======
conn | $PLUGINS_FOLDER/macros.py | value
```

Then you can use `{{ macros.conn.value.<conn_id>.host }}` in your jinja templates like so

```
   task = BashOperator(task_id='read_connection', bash_command='echo macros.conn.value.mssql.host = {{macros.conn.value.mssql.host }}', dag=dag)
```

I also opened an [issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/14597) to add the `conn.value.<conn_id>` syntax natively