# Is it possible to render a variable that has template syntax in jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I have a variable in my python code like:

```py
template_var = "{{ a_macro('var') }}"
```

Is it possible to have that `template_var` rendered in my template? Doing the following prints it as-is:

```
{{ params.template_var}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "rendered in my template"? What exactly do you expect the final result to be?

Comment: first try, next ask (when you get error message - and show FULL error message)

Comment: I don't know what is your problem but `{` and `}` have special meanings so it may need to use `\{` and `\}` in template_var. But It can be other problem. It put template var but it may treat is as normal string and `a_macro` can be useless - you may havet to render template again to recognize `a_macro` and use it.

Comment: @furas You are right that it require to template again. However I believe OP question is more about how to utilize Jinja with Airflow capabilities (specifically because OP mentions `params`) - If so there is no need to template again since probably this is more just using `params` in a wrong manner.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share code so I guess `a_macro`  is a [user defined macro](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial.html#templating-with-jinja) that you created and what you are doing is something like:

```
op = BashOperator(
    task_id='my_task',
    bash_command="python script.py --key {{ params.template_var}}",
    params={'template_var': "{{ a_macro('var') }}"}
    )
```

This is not going to work.
You can not pass Jinja macros with `params`. Templated values needs to be set directly in the templated field.
In the above example [`bash_command`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/0a99be741108470608a81964007aaf0a83f66a9f/airflow/operators/bash.py#L125) is a templated field so you need to do:

```
op = BashOperator(
    task_id='my_task',
    bash_command="python script.py --key {{ a_macro('var') }}",
    )
```

The same goes for any other Airflow operator.

Comment: Huum that is what I thought. 
I perhaps wasn't clear on my question, because I wanted to be as general as possible. 
However, I want to define a string of jinja template to be shared among operators. That is the main goal. Define the string outside of the operator and have it be common to a number of them.

Comment: So your real question is how do you create `a_macro()` You can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/65873023/14624409 I explained there how to create a user defined macro and how to use it. Macro is just a python function. You just need to define it, register it and then you can use it.