# DockerOperator Access Airflow Variable

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker-compose, airflow, dockeroperator

I installed Airflow using docker-compose and ran the db init command. I am trying to create a DAG that uses the DockerOperator to execute some script. In my DockerOperator, the script is trying to read Airflow Variables and get Connections using the BaseHook. But it seems that the script in my DockerOperator is connecting to the (empty) sqlalchemy database and not my initialized postgres database that has the populated Connections and Variables set through the UI.

Is there a way to give the DockerOperator context to the Airflow Database containing the Connections and Variables set through the UI?

**My Airflow DAG**

```
from datetime import datetime
from json import dumps

import pendulum
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.models import XCom
from airflow.models.param import Param
from airflow.operators.docker_operator import DockerOperator
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session


local_tz = pendulum.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")  # will affect schedule interval time zone

args = {"owner": "Airflow"}

SYNC_SCRIPT_DAG = "sync_script_dag_v1"


@provide_session
def cleanup_xcom(session=None, **context):
    print("Cleaning up!!!")
    dag = context["dag"]
    dag_id = dag._dag_id
    session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.dag_id == dag_id).delete()


#################### Define Tasks #####################
## Change Python Executor
with DAG(
    dag_id=SYNC_SCRIPT_DAG,
    default_args=args,
    catchup=False,
    start_date=datetime(2020, 7, 8, tzinfo=local_tz),
    max_active_runs=1,
    tags=["production"],
    schedule_interval=None,
    params={
        # these env vars are expected by the script
        "SOURCE_ONE": "source_two_credential",  # credential ID in Airflow 
        "LOG_LEVEL": "INFO",
        "NUM_WORKER_THREADS": "10",
    },
    on_failure_callback=cleanup_xcom,
    on_success_callback=cleanup_xcom,
) as dag:

    @task(task_id="get_airflow_params_task")
    def get_airflow_params(**context):
        airflow_params = context.get("params")
        return dumps(airflow_params)

    # mask_secret_task = mask_secret()
    get_params_task = get_airflow_params()

    new_task = DockerOperator(
        task_id="my_task_id",
        image="sync-script:latest",
        api_version="auto",
        auto_remove=True,

        # SOURCE_ONE_JIRA_USER should evaluate to the connection dict for Airflow source_two_credential ID
        command="""main.py
            --SOURCE_ONE_JIRA_USER '{{ conn[params.SOURCE_TWO] }}'
            --airflow_params '{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_airflow_params_task')}}'
        """,
        environment={
            "YML_CONFIG": "yml_config",
        },
        docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
        network_mode="host",
        force_pull=True,
        docker_conn_id="harbor_credentials",
    )

    get_params_task >> new_task
```

Now knowing that there is no way to connect to the Airflow Variables or connections from the DockerOperator, I removed the original Error I was getting.

What I was hoping for is a way to pass in via Airflow params, a connection_id and later pass that connection dictionary to my Python script using the DockerOperator. This allows different users triggering the dag to pass in their own credential_id instead of having to overwrite it.

Comment: the error points to sqlite3.OperationalError and not Postgres.

Comment: I understand that. But this is because it is not using the Airflow context from my deployment, instead it is checking the airflow variables stored in the local package "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/***/models/variable.py". My question is how do I get the DockerOperator to use the Variables from my Airflow deployment?

Comment: what is the value of AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN environment variable ? is it postgresql+psycopg2:.... or sqlite: ?

Comment: Its postgresql.

postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow

Comment: as I understand the auth.py is inside the docker and there you installed local airflow. you can pass the variable value from your operator definition (in the DAG) to the command.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it relies on xcom, sensitive credentials will be displayed in the xcom tab in the Airflow UI. I can add a stage to clean up xcom for the task exposing the credentials at the very end, but this would be the last resort. I was hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Why not using jinja? for example  `command="auth.py --airflowmode {{ var.value.MY_INITIALIZED_VAR }}"`

Comment: To clarify - when you are inside the docker env you don't have access to the "outside" e.g you can not access your Airflow instance objects. So anything you need to run your task you must pass via `command`/`environment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are executing within `DockerOperator` is in a "closed environment" it can not access the Airflow resources. Should you need them then you must pass them when initializing `DockerOperator`.

The `command` parameter is templated field so simply use Jinja to achieve that:

```
p1_auth_task = DockerOperator(
    task_id="auth_v1",
    image="tako:latest",
    api_version="auto",
    auto_remove=True,
    command="auth.py --airflowmode {{ var.value.MY_INITIALIZED_VAR }}",
    docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
    network_mode="bridge",
    mount_tmp_dir=False
)
```

You can also pass with `environment` if you prefer.

**Edit:**
Since you are after connection then simply use the connection macro as explained in [use Airflow connection from a jinja template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65826404/use-airflow-connection-from-a-jinja-template/65873023#65873023)

In your case:

```
epic_task = DockerOperator(
    task_id="epic_task",
    image="sync-script:latest",
    api_version="auto",
    auto_remove=True,
    command="main.py",
    environment={
        "YML_CONFIG": "configs/epic_config.yaml",
        "AIRFLOW_PARAMS_SOURCE_ONE_HOST": "{{ conn.SOURCE_ONE.host }}",
        "AIRFLOW_PARAMS_SOURCE_TWO_HOST": "{{ conn.SOURCE_TWO.host }}",
    },
    docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
    network_mode="host",
    force_pull=True
)
```

Comment: I'm passing in the credential name to use via Airflow params. Ideally the script inside Docker would get the credentials login and password. I updated the the code in my question. Jinja would be great if the credentials didn't change, but since they are dynamic I have to pull them from Airflow params, so something like this wouldn't work: 

command=" main.py --airflowparams {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_airflow_params_task').get('SOURCE_ONE_JIRA_USER') }}"

Comment: Airflow has `{{ conn.my_conn_id }}` macro. you can pass your connection details directly. There is no need to push it to xcom by another task see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65826404/use-airflow-connection-from-a-jinja-template/65873023#65873023

Comment: That would work if my connection id is static. But, depending on the user kicking off the DAG, can pass in via params, their conn id. 

    params={
        # these env vars are expected by the script
        "SOURCE_TWO": "user_a_source_two_credentials",
        "SOURCE_ONE": "user_b_source_one_credentials",
        "LOG_LEVEL": "INFO",
        "NUM_WORKER_THREADS": "10",
    },

Comment: You add more information in every comment. Please edit the question with your full needs. It would be easier to help you when all information is present. You didn't mention such dynamic need before - in the code you shown there are two hard coded connections. Once all information is given I will try to assist