# string to dictionary not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I am trying to fetch the secrets in the airflow using `bash-command` using below code and it gives me the output as shown:

```
demo =  Variable.get("sample", default_var="undefined")
 
bash_command='echo "The value of the account variable is: {var}"'.format(var=demo)
```

**Output:**

```
{account:some-value,user:some-value,password:some-value}
```

Now, I am trying to convert this string into a dictionary but somehow it is not working. I tried `json.loads(s)` where it has the above output in the form of a string enclosed with single quotes but it gives me the below error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

so how can I convert this into a dictionary?

**P.S.**: I don't want to go the dirty way of using a `split` on this string for example.

**UPDATE-1:**

As per suggested by Elad, I wanted to configure the connection but somehow I am **not** supposed to configure it in the `Airflow UI` so therefore, so I followed the steps from [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/connections-secrets-manager.html#connections-sm-samples) and the underlying link for the code samples.

Based on that and Elad's suggestion, I have modified my code as below:

```
def read_from_aws_sm_fn():
    ### set up Secrets Manager
    hook = BaseHook(client_type='secretsmanager')
    client = hook.get_client_type('secretsmanager')
    response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId='airflow/variables/secret-name')
    myConnSecretString = response["SecretString"]

    return myConnSecretString

user_macros = {
     'get_schema': read_from_aws_sm_fn
 }

with DAG(
    dag_id="aws_secrets_variables",
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    user_defined_macros=user_macros) as dag:

    BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_command",
        bash_command="
        export account={{ get_schema }};")
```

It gives me the below error:

```
export account=<function read_from_aws_sm_fn at 0x7fbce62fa170>;
```

Comment: You're trying to use a JSON loader to load a string that isn't JSON.  Whatever you come up with, it's going to be dirty.

Comment: What's the format used to produce the string? Use a parser for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow can deserialize variables for you. Have you tried:

```py
Variable.get("sample", default_var="undefined", deserialize_json=True)
```

If that doesn't work, you can try

```py
import ast
demo =  Variable.get("sample", default_var="undefined")
demo_dict = ast.literal_eval(demo)
bash_command='echo "The value of the account variable is: {var}"'.format(var=demo_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set your connection details in Airflow Connection not in Variable.
You can set a Generic connection:

[image]

(Note: password is masked for security reasons)

Now that you have a connection you can reference the values you need with macros as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65873023/14624409).

Assuming you named your connection `my_conn` the code will be:

```
BashOperator(
    task_id="my_task",
    bash_command="""echo The value of the account is login: {{ conn.my_conn.login }}, password: {{ conn.my_conn.password }}"""
)
```

When executing the task:

Render tab:
[image]

Log tab:
[image]

Note again: password is masked for security reasons. This is just for display if you will pass the value to an actual script it will pass the password you have.

If you prefer using Variable  (which I do not recommend as it might expose passwords) then, assuming you have variable called `my_conn_var`:
[image]

Your code can be:

```
BashOperator(
    task_id="my_task",
    bash_command="""echo The value of the account is login: {{ var.json.my_conn_var }}"""
)
```

which will give:

[image]

or you can pick the keys from the json:

```
BashOperator(
    task_id="my_task",
    bash_command="""echo The value of the account is login: {{ var.json.my_conn_var.account }}"""
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer, @Elad. However, as I have mentioned, I have my creds stored in the secrets manager. How can I access that?

Comment: @RushHour Airflow supports secret manager as integration https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/secrets-backends/aws-secrets-manager.html#aws-secrets-manager-backend

Comment: Since it was not related to the output I was looking for I didn't mention that I am using MWAA but I was not able to follow this link where they are creating the connection URI https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/connections-secrets-manager.html#connections-sm-samples

Comment: @RushHour see update answer about using Variable

Comment: Can you let me know which part of the answer is referring to the secrets manager? I don't want to store any external variables in the Airflow environment. Sorry for the dumb question but can you help me here in your answer to understand the SM part?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you stored the variable. i just showed it as an example. Storing it in secret manager should work the same.

Comment: I will try it out but thanks for suggesting the best practice. I ll come back to you with the result

Comment: I explored your answer and if I am not wrong, then I think I need to set up the connection with the values in the Airflow UI but that's not what I am not looking for. I wanted to read the secrets from `SecretsManager`. It's just that I am not supposed to configure the Airflow UI. So, I followed the official documentation and then followed your approach. Can you have look at the `UPDATE-1` in the question?

Comment: @RushHour Airflow doesn't care where the connection stored. it can be in the DB (via the UI), it can be in env var or in custom secret backend. it does not matter. all reads are the same.